# how to use binding from a grid to an HTML template?

Tags: binding, grid, gxt

is it possible to use GXT's binding mechanism to bind a `Grid` to an `Html` (or other `Widget` implementation for that matter)?

it seems from [the examples](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#basicbinding) that it's only applicable for forms (`FormBinding`), while my purpose is to have a `Template` updating a widgets inner element, driven by the grid's `SelectionChangedEvent`s sending the models for that template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding grids and generic components directly is apparently not possible at the current version of GXT, anyhow this is an alternative solution offered as a workaround:

I just made use of the examples [Grid Binding](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#gridbinding) and [Templates](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#templates) to support your requirement. Here is the modified code

```
@Override
protected void onRender(Element parent, int index) {
    super.onRender(parent, index);
    setStyleAttribute("margin", "10px");

    ContentPanel cp = new ContentPanel();

    cp.setHeading("Form Bindings");
    cp.setFrame(true);
    cp.setSize(800, 400);
    cp.setLayout(new RowLayout(Orientation.HORIZONTAL));

    final LayoutContainer panel = new LayoutContainer(new FlowLayout());

    Grid<Stock> grid = createGrid();
    grid.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

    final Template template = new Template(getTemplate());
    grid.getSelectionModel().addListener(Events.SelectionChange, new Listener<SelectionChangedEvent<Stock>>() {
        public void handleEvent(SelectionChangedEvent<Stock> be) {
            if (be.getSelection().size() > 0) {
                template.overwrite(panel.getElement(), Util.getJsObject(be.getSelectedItem()));
            } else {
                panel.removeAll();
            }
        }
    });
    cp.add(grid, new RowData(.6, 1));
    cp.add(panel, new RowData(.4, 1));

    add(cp);
}

private native String getTemplate() /*-{
    var html = [ '<p>Name: {name}</p>', '<p>Symbol: {symbol}</p>',
            '<p>Last: {last}</p>', '<p>Last Updated: {date}</p>', ];
    return html.join("");
}-*/;
```

Add these modifications to the [Grid Binding](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#gridbinding) example. Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Ganesh

Comment: yeah i was thinking along the lines of this solution, but i was hoping for a generic binding mechanism in GXT to work with all sorts of components. i aborted this direction in the meanwhile, but it seems like the plausible solution for this problem. accepting this as the answer, thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: note i edited your answer, as it offers no solution with respect to my question, but a workaround by firing selection events instead of using the binding mechanism.